# The value of $\sum_{1\leq l< m <n}^{} \frac{1}{5^l3^m2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math

How to solve this summation ? Also, I'm not sure what does $1\leq l< m <n$ supposed to imply in the development of summation form.

$$\sum_{1\leq l< m <n}^{} \frac{1}{5^l3^m2^n}$$

This one is from the Galois-Noether Contest in 2018:
[Galois-Contest](https://www.obm.org.br/content/uploads/2018/05/Prova_OBM_U_2018_Primeira_Fase.pdf)

Comment: I get $\frac{\frac1{30}}{1-\frac1{30}}\frac{\frac16}{1-\frac16}\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align*}\sum_{1\leq l< m <n}^{} \frac{1}{5^l3^m2^n}&=\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^l}\sum_{m=l+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^m}\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\\&=\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^l}\sum_{m=l+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^m}\cdot\frac{1}{2^m}\\&=\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^l}\cdot\frac{1}{6^l}\cdot\frac15\\&=\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac1{30}}-1\right)\cdot\frac15\\&=\frac{1}{29\cdot5}\end{align*}
or rather $$\frac{1}{(5\cdot3\cdot2-1)(3\cdot2-1)(2-1)}$$

Comment: (+1) I get $\left(\frac1{30}+\frac1{30^2}+\frac1{30^3}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac16+\frac1{6^2}+\frac1{6^3}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots\right)$ which is $\frac{\frac1{30}}{1-\frac1{30}}\frac{\frac16}{1-\frac16}\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}$ which matches your answer.

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$
\sum_{1\leq l<m<n}\frac{1}{5^l3^m2^n}=\sum_{l\geq1}\left(\frac{1}{5^l}\sum_{m>l}\left(\frac{1}{3^m}\sum_{n>m}\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\right).
$$
Now 
$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=2^{-m},
$$
so we can reduce the sum to 
$$
\sum_{l\geq1}\left(\frac{1}{5^l}\sum_{m>l}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^m\right).
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Sure ! Thank you very much ! +1

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:**

You have
$$
\sum_{1\leq \ell<m<n} \frac{1}{5^\ell3^m2^n}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{5^\ell3^m2^n}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^m}\sum_{\ell=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{5^\ell} \tag{1}
$$
Since $$
\sum_{\ell=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{5^\ell} = \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1-1/5^{m-1}}{1-1/5} = \frac{1-1/5^{m-1}}{4} = \frac{1-5/5^{m}}{4}
$$
you can rewrite it as
$$
\sum_{1\leq \ell<m<n} \frac{1}{5^\ell3^m2^n}
= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-5/5^{m}}{3^m}
= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^m}
- \frac{5}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{15^m}\,.
$$
Since $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^m}$ and $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{15^m}$ can be computed as [...], you can rewrite [...]

Can you continue?

Comment: Sure ! Thank you for your attention +1

Comment: Note that it is easier with the reverse order on $l$, $m$, $n$ though.

Comment: Yes, that's very possible. When the upper limit is infinity, the annoying extra terms won't appear.

Comment: Mmh. Why the downvote?

Comment: I got a downvote as well at the same time, I gathered that some people systematically downvote every answer when they close a question.

Comment: That's... Misguided. Oh, well.